# replacing a cell value using IF statement in gs

Tags: google-sheets

I come from a VBA background and am learning GS. I want to replace the value in the cell with the new value based on the IF statement. I have the following code which does not work. What did I make wrong? Thanks.

```
function ChangeCharacter() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = ss.getRange("A16");
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    if (cell.Value == "BoogeyMan") {
        cell.setValue("ToothFairy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, consider adding what kind of output/error you are getting right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are really close. Change  if (cell.Value == "BoogeyMan") to if (cellValue == "BoogeyMan"). That will fix it.

works! If I wanted to go through 20 cells and replace BoogeyMan with ToothFairy I tried the following, didn't work.

```
    function ChangeCharacter() 
    { var ss = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
    for (r=1; r<21; r++) { 
    if (ss.getRange(r,1) === "BoogeyMan") { 
    ss.getRange(r,1).setValue("ToothFairy"); 
    } 
    } 
    } – ronald 1 min ago    edit
```

If you want to loop through a column do this:

```
 function ChangeCharacter1() 
    { var ss = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
    var lr=ss.getLastRow()
    var data=ss.getRange(1, 1, lr,1).getValues()
    for (r=1; r<data.length; r++) { 
       if (data[r][0] == "BoogeyMan") { 
       ss.getRange(r+1, 1).setValue("ToothFairy"); 
    }}}
```